# Cannot connect to the internet. Local Area Connection 2 adapter is disabled

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Short version: I cannot connect to the internet.
Long version:
I have been dealing with this issue for more than one year. After waking from hibernation my DELL 15 XPS (Win 7 Pro SP1) sometimes would not find any wireless connection. Running the Troubleshooting would usually fix the problem by resetting the wireless adapter, or I could fix it by manually resetting it via the keyboard fn+f2 command. The same issue ("no connections available") would happen sometimes while I am streaming video.
However, once in a while when this problem arises the keyboard command fn+f2 would not work at all, and the troubleshooting would not solve the problem. It would show "problems found: The Local Area Connection 2 adapter is disabled", and I would "try these repairs as administrator" without success. Basically, it appears that in these cases the system would not be able to re-enable the wireless network adapter. So far, resetting the laptop, logging in as Administrator (I had to create the Admin profile 2 months ago to install a software, but this is unlikely to be the problem, as I had this issue for the last year), and running the troubleshoot again had worked. Not this time.

As of now, I am stuck without any internet connection. In Device Manager I find a rather mutilated list of network adapters (fewer than I usually see): Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobile Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64 and Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller, plus two more Bluetooth Devices. It seems that the system cannot find my network adapters anymore (I scanned for hardware changes to no avail).

Under Control Panel>Network and the internet>Network Connections I see only Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client Connection (network cable unplugged), and Local Area Connection (network cable unplugged), all with a big red cross on them.

I tried:
- several system reboots over the last 24 hours
- system restore, but it cannot be completed because "one file could not be changed" despite having disabled my antivirus during the process. And it did not solve the issue
- I had already prohibited months ago the system from shutting down the networks adapters by going to device manager and unflagging the option in the Power management tab for each device under network adapters.
- drivers for my adapters were up to date a few days ago
- reset TCP/IP and IPv4 and IPv6 configuration using the netsh command via the cmd prompt run as administrator (https://pandapow.co/how-to/win-reset-adapter/)
- uninstalled and re-installed the Realtek Controller

I am running out of options. Thank you for any help you can provide.

UPDATE:
Unexpectedly, I turned on my laptop a few days later and it could connect to the internet. This was before any windows update and without any intervention on my part. The day after I left for vacation. Now I am back and I have the same problem. Rebooting the machine several times does not help.
Please help me with this frustrating situation...

SECOND UPDATE:
I found a way to fix it.. for now. I restarted my laptop and pressed f8, then chose to load the "last known working configuration", and the wireless adapter was working. So, it is not clear what caused the problem, nor whether I permanently removed it, but at least this got me out of troubles. I will keep updating if the problems comes back. Please do continue to share solutions if you know how to solve this problem.

LAST UPDATE:
The fix has been working so far. I still get the wireless not working whenever I put my laptop to sleep and I wake it back, but the troubleshoot fixed it every time. So not ideal, but I could always use the laptop internet connection when I needed it, which is a great leap forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out that I had hit the Wireless Button on my hp elitebook folio 9480m, which was a button that I hadn't previously noticed next to my mute button.

My laptop couldn't tell me why the wireless capability had been turned off, however, until I went to the Network and Sharing Center > Troubleshoot Problems > the Network Adapter troubleshooting pack, and then individually checked each network adapter one at a time (for some reason "All network adapters" didn't find anything, while the individual options did).  That's when it said to hit the wireless button.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP had a Dell not an HP.

Comment: Thank you. No, this was not my problem, the switch of the wireless was on. But it happened on another laptop a few years ago, so I know what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue (network 2 adapter 'disabled' and couldn't fix by running diagnostics - computer didn't recognize internet).  My laptop was an HP 9480m, IT told me to remove the battery - THEN hold down power button for 30 seconds, and see if it worked....to my surprise, it did.  Now recognizing wireless.  Next time will try the wireless button thing.....